# How Secure Is This Login System? (Using Cookies In PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, security, cookies

I've created a login page and I'm using Cookies. Down below is the code for Login Page:

Register

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
$errors = array();
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'db123', 'db123', 'db123');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE phone_number = '$username'");
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if($result->num_rows == 0) {
     echo 'Username Not Found!';
} elseif($data['otp_verified'] === 'false'){
echo 'OTP Not Verified, Click Here To Verify Your Number';
}
else{
    $encryptpass=md5($_POST['password']);
    $cookie_username = $_POST['username'];
    if($encryptpass == $data['password']){
    echo 'Login Is Verified';
    $Month = 86400 + time(); 
     setcookie('user', $cookie_username, $Month);
    header("location:dashboard.php");
    }
    else{
    echo 'Login/Password Incorrect :(';
    }
}
$mysqli->close();   
}

?>
```

And Finally, Here's the code for dashboard.php and all other pages which are restricted:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_COOKIE['user']))
{
header("location:index.php");
die();
}
?>
```

My Questions: 
1. How Secure Is This Login System?
2. How I can improve it?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's not very secure. Use `password_hash()` instead of `md5()`. Use prepared statement. Do not use cookies, use sessions.

Comment: just like the statement above, after doing those things, you could probably use oath instead and save you the trouble doing it right

Comment: Okay, But session is destroyed when user close the browser. I want users to stay logged in for specific interval of time :/

Comment: You can implement a remember me feature, Paul. But be careful of that, it can introduce security holes - and has to be done properly. But always, always use sessions for this, not cookies.

Comment: Sessions can survice browser closure if you specify their [lifetime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

Comment: Hi  @KIKO Software can you tell me about the problems with the code? Thanks :)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'd say it's off-topic (hence my downvote). I feel like this question would be indeed better for code review.

Comment: Please read the comment by Qirel, he addresses the major problems.

Comment: @treyBake That could indeed be a valid reason to downvote, but Paul is not to know, unless you tell him.... which you just did...

Comment: @KIKOSoftware ^^ good point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non-exhaustive list of problems/solutions:

- Your code is difficult to read because it is not properly indented.
- You should [use prepared statemens to guard against SQL-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
- You give hints to hackers by having different error messages. When the username is correct and the password wrong you say: "Login/Password Incorrect :(", but if the username is wrong you say: "Username Not Found!". That way a hacker can know if an username is correct, and half the job is done.
- Better not use `md5()` for password encryption.
- Use [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for handling passwords.
- Do not store the username in a cookie. Again, you're leaking information.
- Don't use cookies, there's just no need to do that, use sessions and store information on the server, not on the user's machine.
- You seem to have stored usernames as `phone_number`. So which one is it? It is either an username or a phone number, it cannot be both. Even if you use phone numbers as user names, call them what they are.
- Sloppy coding: `$errors = array();` is not used anywhere. You don't check the result of `new mysqli()`, the connection might fail. Same is true for `$mysqli->query()`.
- You take care to close the database, but then why don't you release the query result with `$result->close();`? Either do both, or none.

Security is a difficult topic, it's really hard to get it right, and what might be good today, might be bad tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Its very unsecure

- there can be sql injections (because the username goes directly to the databasa)
- md5 is obsolete since years
- you save the username unencrypted

Comment: As you daid: (there can be sql injections (because the username goes directly to the databasa), What are the best practices to resolve this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts :)

Comment: you can use a libary like [meekro db](https://meekro.com/)
or use
`private static function SecureParam($param) {
        return stripslashes(addslashes($param));
    }`
to avoid sql injection

Comment: The most definitive and ONLY proper way of preventing SQL injection, is by using a prepared statement. Don't think you can strip and filter the input, you'll end up mangling the data more than you should - just use a prepared statement. Its simpler and better.

Comment: And encrypting the username will be a massive pain to work around. It's not needed, it can be in cleartext. The password on the other hand; use `password_hash()` instead of `md5()`.

Comment: So, I need to use Prepared Statement(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4JYwRIjX6c) and password_hash to make it secure?

Comment: Use prepared statement with placeholders (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), use `password_hash()` when registering, `password_verify()` when logging in, use sessions instead of cookies. That's a good start :-)